Nginx location block disables PHP
I know that Nginx location blocks follow a certain order, but I can't quite wrap my head around it and how to achieve the following.
# enable PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
}

# allow only a specific user agent in a certain location
location ~ /panel/install/ {
  if ($http_user_agent !~ "agentname") { return 403; }
}

So it partially works. PHP is enabled, and if user agent condition fails, it will return forbidden. However, if the user agent condition succeeds, PHP no longer works and it will download the file instead. Now I understand this is probably how it's supposed to work. But I can't quite understand how to achieve the above. I could of course include the PHP block also inside the second block, but that seems incredibly clumsy.
Thanks for suggestions!

The configuration snippet in your question does not behave the way you describe. Perhaps you have been experimenting with the ^~ operator.
If you used location ^~ /panel/install/ then the PHP file would indeed be downloaded.
Having said that, using the ^~ operator and including the location ~ \.php$ as a nested block is a perfectly acceptable and common method to solve this problem.
For example:
# enable PHP
location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
}

# allow only a specific user agent in a certain location
location ^~ /panel/install/ {
  if ($http_user_agent !~ "agentname") { return 403; }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
  }
}


If you want to eliminate duplication, place the location ~ \.php$ block into a separate file and use include statements to pull it in at the appropriate places.
For example:
File snippets/location-php.conf:
location ~ \.php$ {
  include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
  fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
}

Replacement configuration:
# enable PHP
include snippets/location-php.conf;

# allow only a specific user agent in a certain location
location ^~ /panel/install/ {
  if ($http_user_agent !~ "agentname") { return 403; }
  include snippets/location-php.conf;
}


Thanks for the answer and insight. I may have pasted incorrectly as the second location block was ~ location /panel/install/. I'm still a bit surprised that there is no other option than to include php.conf in each separate location when just trying to limit access to a specific location.

You can also used a named location block (e.g. location @php {) to avoid repeating config

@suncat100 there are always other solutions, but I would argue that nesting the location blocks is probably the most efficient. For example, you could use one or more map blocks to determine access rights.

One can also do the nesting other way around - add the access control location inside the \.php location.
